# How can I make the user be able to edit the script of the chrome app I developed

Tags: edit, google-chrome-app, configure

I'm developing a Chrome app, and want to make the users be able to edit the script. I want them to be able to add things to it, and adjust it. Is there any way to do this with Chrome apps?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

normally I would suggest `eval();`,
but you cain't do that in a chrome app for security reasons.

But I guess uploading it to [github](https://github.com/) may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

An app can use `eval` in [sandboxed pages](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox).

["Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely."](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval) covers this topic.

Depending on what part of the logic you want to make customizable, this may work for you, but it's going to be complex. It's a bit like writing a virtual machine.